# Include Google Git code in Android project

Tags: android, git

I want to add the code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/71492ab60892087f3e989b876b82f5c0249b3b14/src/com/android/datetimepicker to my project and I couldn't find a way to download it as a library. How can I do that?

Is there another way to use this code in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I couldn't find a way to download it as a library

That is because it is not a library. It is a random hunk of source code.

> Is there another way to use this code in my project?

Download the source files, add them to your project, and fix up any references to things that you do not have access to. If the code depends on resources, you will have to try to find those in the Android source code base and blend them into your project as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a library project and if you want to use it in your project copy the project to your workspace.